# boost multiprecision + numeric bindings + LAPACK

Tags: c++, boost, ublas, boost-ublas

I'm trying to implement some numeric procedures using the `boost`  multiprecision template library in combination with numeric bindings for a `lapack` backend.

However, the template resolution doesn't seem to work as intended. I've been able to narrow it down to this minimal example:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/symmetric.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/bindings/traits/ublas_matrix.hpp>
#include "boost/numeric/bindings/lapack/syev.hpp" 
#include "boost/numeric/bindings/lapack/workspace.hpp"

typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<100> > SuperFloat;
typedef std::numeric_limits<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<100> > SuperFloatPrecision;
typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<SuperFloat> Matrix;
typedef boost::numeric::ublas::symmetric_matrix<SuperFloat> MatrixSym;

inline int diagonalize(Matrix& eigenvectors, boost::numeric::ublas::vector<SuperFloat>& eigenvalues) {
  int r = boost::numeric::bindings::lapack::syev( 'U', eigenvectors, eigenvalues, boost::numeric::bindings::lapack::minimal_workspace() );
  return r;
}

int main(){
  std::cout << "hello!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

which yields this error message:

```
boost/numeric/bindings/lapack/syev.hpp: In instantiation of ‘int boost::numeric::bindings::lapack::syev(char, A&, W&, boost::numeric::bindings::lapack::minimal_workspace) [with A = boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<100u> > >; W = boost::numeric::ublas::vector<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<100u> > >]’:
test.cxx:13:137:   required from here
boost/numeric/bindings/lapack/syev.hpp:163:8: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( (boost::mpl::or_< boost::is_same< matrix_structure, traits::symmetric_t >
        ^
In file included from ./boost/numeric/bindings/traits/traits.hpp:18:0,
                 from ./boost/numeric/bindings/traits/ublas_matrix.hpp:17,
                 from test.cxx:3:
./boost/numeric/bindings/traits/matrix_traits.hpp: In instantiation of ‘char boost::numeric::bindings::traits::matrix_uplo_tag(SymmM&) [with SymmM = boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<100u> > >]’:
boost/numeric/bindings/lapack/syev.hpp:181:47:   required from ‘int boost::numeric::bindings::lapack::syev(char, A&, W&, boost::numeric::bindings::lapack::minimal_workspace) [with A = boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<100u> > >; W = boost::numeric::ublas::vector<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<100u> > >]’
test.cxx:13:137:   required from here
./boost/numeric/bindings/traits/matrix_traits.hpp:141:56: error: no type named ‘uplo_type’ in ‘struct boost::numeric::bindings::traits::matrix_traits<boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_dec_float<100u> > > >’
       typedef typename matrix_traits<SymmM>::uplo_type uplo_t;
```

Is it at all possible to use `lapack` as a backend for boost `UBLAS` templated to multiprecision, or is this a futile endeavour? 
Are there any other ways to do, say, an eigenvector decomposition of a ublas multiprecision matrix?